# parsing web page which is changing real time in JAVA

Tags: java, parsing, html

Heres what i want to do. Im quite a beginner with this so maybe a lame question, But, I want to implement gui application in java wich gets data from sports livescore pages 
e.g

```
http://www.futbol24.com/Live/


http://livescore.com/
```

and parse it (somehow) in my app...and then i will be able to store it in for example jtable ,save full time results in database,playing sounds after goal is scored and so on

What is the best way to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be almost impossible to parse an HTML document from a live web page and get specific information from it. If you did manage to work out exactly where in the document the data is, the page structure could change at any time. The scores might not even be in the HTML - they could be fetched by Javascript in the page.

I suggest you find an RSS feed of the information you want. Then you'll only have a nice, small piece of XML to parse. That's what it's for.

Comment: Thank you for making it clear.But as i said above im new to this features of java> so Lets say i found Rss feed http://www.soccerstand.com/rss/soccer ...question remains ? is there some tool/framework which makes it easier to get data ?

Comment: For parsing XML with Java, see http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/java-xml-tutorials/